# What are the maximum sizes allows for Preference Pane icons in OS X?

Tags: macos, icons, size, preferences

What are the maximum sizes allows for Preference Pane icons in OS X?

I've looked through the OS X Style Guide and I can't find the maximum size of these, esp with regards to Retina and Non-Retina assets.

E.g. These from XCode 4.6

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with a quote from Apple's HIG which states to design icons at 32x32 and 32x32@2x for toolbars (the icons you display in your picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the maximum size for an icon is `512x512` for non retina and `1024x1024` on retina displays. However, in the preference pane, icons are displayed much smaller.

I don't know the answer to your question. It depends on the size of the display, but it is safe to assume than in your situation, on a retina display, you won't need more than `64x64`. However, I encourage you to develop the full set, as it is not much extra work, that way you will be prepared to use them on better displays in the future. Also, you will have a good-looking version to display elsewhere, should the need arise later.

See [**Designing Toolbar Icons**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

They say:

> Create icons for standard- and high-resolution displays. You need to
>   supply two resources: 32x32 and 32x32@2x. See Table 5-1 for the
>   corresponding canvas sizes.

*Note: 32x32@2x = 64x64 px*

**Additional resources:**

- [Icon design guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/OSXHIGuidelines.pdf)

[image]